# Templates - Exercises

Tags: c++, templates

As I mentioned in my yesterday's post, I'm trying to teach myself templates from the book: Templates: The Complete Guide. And although I'm finding this book very nicely presented and material there is explained really well there are no exercises attached after each chapter to test your knowledge, like it is in The C++ Language by B.S for example and had done all exercises from "The C++" I really feel benefit from doing them. So what I'm asking today is: Does anyone know where can I get exercises with templates.

Comment: I wonder if Stroustrup's new book has more exercises?  It's meant to be a textbook I believe.

Comment: Yes, it's full of exercises and they are really make difference. I myself realized that even thoug I was very concentraited when reading and tried to grasp new concepts only doing exercises really hammered them into my head.

Comment: Can't you set exercises to yourself? What is your level? Implement a template function, class (e.g a stack), something with specialization (e.g for objects / pointers), calculate primes at compile time, implement `boost::enable_if` etc.

Comment: Well, I think my level is lets say medium basic. I mean from what you've just listed I could do (and did) everything except calculating primes at compile time and I didn't try to implement boost::enable_if. But thanks for your comment

Comment: @UncleBens Well as for setting these exercises my self its rather like me asking, does anyone know good footbal club where I can learn (with a proper coach) how to play footbal and someone would answer, can't you just buy a ball and start kicking it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ Template Metaprogramming; Concepts, Tools, and Techniques from Boost and beyond - this book really rocks.

Answer (score 0):

[Thinking in C++ by Bruce Eckel](http://www.mindview.net/Books/TICPP/ThinkingInCPP2e.html)

Comment: But if I'm not mistaken there is just bit of templates not full book dedicated to them, am I right?   
And another thing, once I've tried to read one of his book and I just couldn't understand why this man in order to explain how to input something to console needed wrap this in unimportant and totally irrelevant stuff. So basically I stopped reading this book. What I'm really looking for is book, website or anything else where I could find material and exercises dedicated just to templates.