# Debugging metaprograms

Tags: c++, debugging, metaprogramming

Is there any way to check step by step what's going on in let's say template? I mean how it is instantiated step by step and so on?

In book I've mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358398/templates-exercises) ,

I found (2 minutes ago) quite interesting example of how binary could be implemented as a metafunction.

```
template <unsigned long N>
   struct binary
   {
       static unsigned const value
          = binary<N/10>::value << 1   // prepend higher bits
            | N%10;                    // to lowest bit
   };

   template <>                           // specialization
   struct binary<0>                      // terminates recursion
   {
       static unsigned const value = 0;
   };
```

and I think it could be quite useful to be able to see step by step what's been done during the instantiation of this template.
Thanks for your replies.

Comment: Don't accept that quickly, maybe someone else has a better tip :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best i've seen this far was the research paper on [Templight](http://gsd.web.elte.hu/contents/articles/gpce06.pdf), but i am not aware of any publicized implementation.

You can help yourself much though by using descriptive static (i.e. compile time) assertions - see e.g. Boosts [static assert](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/boost_staticassert.html) or [MPLs asserts](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/asserts.html). In some cases it can help to provoke a compile error (e.g. by using static asserts) to get a template instantiation trace from the compiler.
Also there is nothing preventing you from a runtime output of meta-function results for testing.

Comment: Yes I think runtime output will suite me well. Thanks

Comment: Having said that now I've encounter a problem with output. I've tried something like so:
cout << N;
but I'm getting errors. Help.

Comment: You can't just throw output statements in meta-functions, but you can output values from concrete instantiations of meta-functions, e.g. `std::cout << binary<101>::value`.